# Postgres to TypeORM

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Can anyone please give a TypeORM solution for the below query,

```
select upr.active, pr.preference from user_preferences upr
left join preferences pr
on upr.preferenceid = pr.id
where upr.userid = 1
```

The output is,

```
active  preference
TRUE    update
TRUE    insert
```

My TypeORM repo names are preferenceRepo, userPreferenceRepo

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply need to do:

```
return  this.userPreferenceRepo.createQueryBuilder('upr') 
    .leftJoin("upr.preferenceid", "pr") // replace preferenceid with the name of the colmun that relate user and Preference entity 
   .select(["upr.active","pr.preference"])
   .where("upr.userid = :id ", { id: id }) 
   .getRawMany();
```

Comment: Nice. Yes its working fine. Thank u so much ! - @Youba